# Mathematical notation for formulating a rank score

Tags: modelling

This is a cross-post from [Mathematics forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2380215). As no one has answered it yet, I fIgured post here as well.

I would like to describe a transform I used to rank my data points. I have recoded my variable columns from $10$ measurements with different range to $n$ (for each measurement) where $n \in \{0,0.5,1\}$.

For columns where measurements were expressed as categorical values I simply recoded the categorical value to either $0$, $0.5$ or $1$ and for continuous variables I recoded the lower quartile as $0$, interquartile as $0.5$ and upper quartile as $1$ and finally I summed the recoded values to produce a single score $\sum n_{i1,..i10} $ for each row.

I am trying to write my method and I'd like to have it in mathematical notation. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this!

Comment: Maybe try https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by "have it in mathematical notation"? Can you give an example of something you consider "in mathematical notation"?

Comment: Also, it would be good to include the link to the cross-post

Comment: Hi bli, Thank you for your comment. By mathematical notation I mean mathematical representation of my transform. I am including the link as you suggested!

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. So can you please try to explain it with some example. Then we may able to help you.

Comment: Have you looked at the dataframe I uploaded in Mathematics forum?

Comment: Yes, I did. But still it not clear.

Comment: I think the problem with your question is two-fold. 1) you don't provide any reproducible data so that we can grasp the details of how you calculate this "rank" score. [See this post for an example how you would make a reproducible example in R to get an idea of what we mean by "reproducible example"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) 2) there is not likely to be a mathematical notation for what you have done, because there is no mathematical formula to convert strings ("I", "II", "III") into numbers. One way that you could potentially solv

Comment: I think that "mathematical notation" does not necessary have to consist in "formulas". One could probably define a bijection between a set of strings and a set of numbers, in proper mathematical notation, and that would validly describe a conversion procedure.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right that there is some valid way of describing the rank score. I imagine in this case it would be something more akin to a key than notation/formula, but if you have an idea how to describe it why don't you add an answer?

Comment: As you pointed out, it is difficult to grasp the details of what the OP wants. Besides, it's been a long time since I last wrote maths formally.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to the problem. I am posting it here in case anyone else come up with the same idea but did not know how to formulate it in mathematical notation!

> $$ \psi_i = \sum_{i=1}^9 S_i $$
>
> where $S_i$ is the score function and defined as:
>
> $$
> S_i = \cases{
>   0 & \text{if $\theta(x_i) < Q_1$ or $\theta(x_i) = $ benign/neutral} \\
>   0.5 & \text{if $Q_1 \leq \theta(x_i) < Q_3$ or $\theta(x_i) = $ possibly damaging/uncertain} \\
>   1 & \text{if $\theta(x_i) \geq Q_3$ or $\theta(x_i) = $ damaging}
> }
> $$
>
> The $\theta(x_i)$ is the pathogenicity or conservation score for variant $x$ as defined by model $i$ and $Q$ denotes the quartile range for scores from M-CAP, CADD, GERP and Phylop models.

Comment: If Q are quartiles, then the last line for damaging shouldn't be $>Q_3$?

Comment: @Konrad and Reza : Can you look into this problem and provide some suggestions. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716192/how-to-convert-a-detailed-mathematical-statistical-compuational-process-into-ma